# Hypersurfaces containing given lines

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, surfaces

Let $L_1, ..., L_n$ be non-intersecting (general, if necessary) lines in $\mathbb P^3$. I need to find the dimension of the space of polynomials of degree $d$, vanishing on these lines.

Cohomologically speaking, its $h_0(\mathbb P^3, I_{\bigsqcup L_i}(d)$. Unfortjnately, the exact sequence $0 \to I_{\bigsqcup L_i}(d) \to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(d) \to \mathcal O_{\bigsqcup L_i}(d) \to 0$ does not help.

Comment: I think it's clear what an estimate of the dimension is. The space of polynomials is projective space of dimension $\binom{d+3}{3}-1$, and the condition of vanishing on a line $L$ cuts out a plane $H_L$ of codimension $d+1$. However, I don't know how to show that, if $L_1,\ldots,L_n$ are general, then $H_{L_1},\ldots,H_{L_n}$ intersect in the right codimension (or if it's even true).