# Quintic hypersurfaces through 7 generic lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Consider 7 generic lines $l_1, \dots, l_7 \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ (in particular, they do not intersect). Denote by $Z$ their union.
$$\dim H^0 \big( \mathbb{P}^3, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3} (4) \big) = \binom{4+3}{3} = 35$$

$$\dim H^0 \big( \mathbb{P}^3, \mathcal{O}_Z(4) ) = 7 \dim H^0( \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} (4) \big) = 7 \times 5 = 35$$

Consider restriction map $R$

$$R: H^0 \big( \mathbb{P}^3, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3} (4) \big) \rightarrow H^0 \big( \mathbb{P}^3, \mathcal{O}_Z(4) \big)$$

**Question** Is $R$ isomorphism?

**Comment 1.** You can reformulate this if you wish. Are there quintic hypersurfaces, passing through these 7 lines? What is $H^1 \big( I_Z(4) \big)$, where $I_Z$ - sheaf of ideals.

**Comment 2.** My question is particular case of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579939/hypersurfaces-containing-given-lines) question. I tried to consider case by case. It is the easiest example, where I do not know the answer. In particular I succeeded to consider [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588490/cubic-hypersurfaces-through-5-generic-lines-in-mathbbp3) case.

Comment: Sorry this doesnt adress your question, but what is your basic reference for this ?

Comment: I am not sure, that I understand you correctly. But when I wrote "this" I made a hyperlink. Click and find corresponding pages. Was your question about this?

Comment: I meant is there a book from which you are working. Or which treats this example of 7 generic lines.

Comment: I do not know any references.